# Usage of "this issues with"

Tags: grammaticality

It has been customary to use the following sentence in official parlance, at the end of transfer orders.

"This issues with the approval of the competent authority"

Is this usage acceptable? This is issued should have been used.

Comment: There's a related question on the English Language Learners SE: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37717/issue-as-an-intransitive-verb

Answer (score 2):

"This is issued with..." is the **transitive** use of the verb "to issue". Or in [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/issue?s=t) speak it's a verb used "with an object"; meaning 21:

> verb (used with object)
>
> **21.** to put out; deliver for use, sale, etc.; put into circulation.

"This issues with" is the **intransitive** use of the verb "to issue". Or in [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/issue?s=t) speak it's a verb used "without an object"; meaning 26:

> verb (used without object)
>
> **26.** to be sent, put forth, or distributed authoritatively or publicly, as a legal writ or money.

Hence the usage in the original quote is acceptable. I wouldn't say it was normal, but the "official parlance" you speak of may use obscure forms of English to sound more pompous.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to know the origin of this official parlance, "This issues with...", is popularly used, but grammatically wrong. It would be grammatically correct if it is, "This is issued... or This is being issued with........" Here, 'This' is a noun, pointing this order or this parlance (not that or these or those or others), and 'issues' is a verb, which would be synchronizing with the singular third person 'this'. In this case, "this issues with... " is correct. But 'this' cannot issue an order. If it is, "He issues with ......" is correct grammatically.
Otherwise, it should read as, "I issue with......." or "I, hereby, issue this with..."

My suggestions are as follows:

1. This is issued with the approval of the competent authority. (Here, 'This' is a pronoun)
2. This order/ordinance/directive/summon is issued with the approval of the competent authority. (Here, 'This' is an adjective).
3. I, hereby, issue this with the approval of the competent authority.

Answer (score -1):

"This issues with" is simply using the present tense.  It is the author pronouncing the authority of the issuance in the breath of its issue.  It clarifies that the parlance wasn't issued previously and only now is being iterated with said authority. It clarifies that this isn't a relaying of the parlance; this *is* the parlance.  This is the source that people can point to.  In short, yes, it's acceptable, and in this context, it's preferred.

If you are asking if "this," presumably the "parlance," can be the subject of "issue" when that which is being issued is the selfsame parlance, then the answer is yes.  A magazine issues with a date on the cover.  Steven King's new book issues in both hardcover and paperback.  This reflexive quality to the verb "issue" is longstanding.

Comment: Your first paragraph is incorrect - this is nothing to do with tense. Your second paragraph is closer, although "this" isn't the "parlance", it is the "transfer order".